# Facebook auth: Something went wrong

Tags: facebook, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Using flutter_facebook_login i'm trying to log in with my account credentials. Unfortunatly, instead of facebook popup with account choosing it redirects me to page with. "Sorry, something went wrong. We are working on it and we'll get it fixed as soon as we can.". The console don't throw any errors. It was working last week but i didn't touch a thing anyhow connected with facebook logging in. 
Is there anything i could do to get any information about the issue?

Comment: What’s the URL of that page you are getting redirected to? Is it from your own app, or a Facebook URL?

Comment: The page opens inside the app, I can't provide url unfortunately.
https://ibb.co/4PwFTsx <-- here's a screenshot

Comment: Okay, I've managed to solve the problem. I was asking facebook_login for 'email' and 'default' permissions. Removing the 'default' solved the issue.
Here's a line snippet for future generations:
`final FacebookLoginResult result = await _facebookLogin.logIn(['email']);`